# C programming: how to ignore an input?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'm new to C language so please don't be harsh on me.  I want to run a program this way : `./test -option 3,2 < text.txt`

I want to execute the program regardless of the file exists or not.

So that `./test -option 3,4,2 < text.txt` is the same as `./test -option 3,4,2` 
 without
getting the message `*-bash: hehe: No such file or directory*`

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure test.c is an executable? .c extensions are generally used for representing C source files...

Comment: my bad, fixed it

Comment: This is I/O redirection, and it happens before your program is even started. You'll have to deal with this in bash.

Comment: Consider making your program take the filename as an argument rather than redirecting `stdin`

Comment: You have no control on bash IO redirection. You are better off doing file handling in C if you want some feature like that.

Comment: You seems to code C on Linux. So read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) with [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), then provide some [mre] in your question (with compilation commands)

Comment: I suggest to use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile your C code on Linux [with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)

Comment: This seems to be an issue to solve for bash, not the C program itself. Consider to ask it an appropriate forum. F.e. https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary:

```
[ -f test.txt ] && ./test -option 3,2 < test.txt || echo "" | ./test -option 3,2
```

In order to avoid repeating the command, you can also use:

```
CMD="./test -option 3,2"; [ -f test.txt ] && $CMD < test.txt || echo "" | $CMD
```

Also, notice that `test` is a command, consider using another name for your program.

Comment: You can delete "*If bash is an option,*". OP shows that s/he is using `bash` with the provided diagnostic.